# ‘to treat the 2nd term specially’

Tags: word-choice

It is a mathematical paper. There are many terms in a series, and the 2nd term is special and has to be treated specially.

How to phrase it?

'to treat the 2nd term individually'?

Comment: This is a perfectly grammatical and idiomatic phrase in English. Without further context, it is not possible to say anything more about it.

Comment: Your first phrasing (**treated specially**) does not need rephrasing. It is better than **individually**.  We can treat every item individually and yet treat them all in the same manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrase '**to treat the 2nd term individually**' is perfectly grammatical and natural. You can also say:

- 'to treat the 2nd term in a special way'